# OnChange on textbox Event calling twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am adding onchange event dynamically using jQuery. When I am changing the textbox the event is firing twice and two times alert boxes are coming sometimes 3 times.

```
if(Country.toUpperCase().indexOf("MALAYSIA")!=-1)
{    debugger;
    if(productDesc.toUpperCase().indexOf("SV")!=-1)
    {                   
        $("#<%=txtlAxis.ClientID%>").change(function()
        {         
                if(productDesc.toUpperCase().indexOf("SV")!=-1)
                {                           
                alert('2');
                }
        });  
    }
}
```

Comment: `adding onchange event dynamically` maybe you are binding the handler several times and all of them are being executed, add more relevant code.

Comment: this looks like a mix of js and c#- what is that element with id  "<%=txtlAxis.ClientID%>"
need more code to zone in your problem

Comment: Joy and leonxki - Its hitting the function fine ( I saw in debug mode ) .. but 2 times..  $("#<%=txtlAxis.ClientID%>") - NO issues with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use unbind in this code?

```
if(Country.toUpperCase().indexOf("MALAYSIA")!=-1)
   {  
        if(productDesc.toUpperCase().indexOf("SV")!=-1)
        {       
            $("#<%=txtlAxis.ClientID%>").unbind();
            $("#<%=txtlAxis.ClientID%>").change(function()
            {         
                 if(productDesc.toUpperCase().indexOf("SV")!=-1)
                 {                           
                    alert('2');
                 }
            });  
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below. `Unbind` the OnChange event and add it again on the fly.

```
if(Country.toUpperCase().indexOf("MALAYSIA")!=-1)
{    
    if(productDesc.toUpperCase().indexOf("SV")!=-1)
    {      
        $('.txtlAxisClass').attr("onchange", "");             
        $("#<%=txtlAxis.ClientID%>").change(function()
        {         
             if(productDesc.toUpperCase().indexOf("SV")!=-1)
             {                           
                alert('2');
             }
        });  
    }
}
```

You are also `Downgrading the Performance` by re-evaluating the below mentioned expression again. So keep it in the variable.

`productDesc.toUpperCase().indexOf("SV")`

Comment: What is different about your code? (It's more helpful if you add a note in your answer about what you added and why)

Comment: Hi MMK and Kanavi and all,
Its fixed. Thank you so much for your reply. MMK unbind() is CORRECT. I used Kanavi's .attr("onchange", "") also but NO USE. Checked in IE8 and CROME. 

Yes Kanavi, I will take that into one variable thx for u r suggesion. StackOverflow ROCKS.

Comment: Kannavi/ MMK, Why .attr("onchange", "") is not working any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed. Thank you so much for your reply. MMK unbind() is CORRECT. I used Kanavi's .attr("onchange", "") also but NO USE. Checked in IE8 and CROME.

Yes Kanavi, I will take that into one variable thx for u r suggesion. StackOverflow ROCKS.

```
       if(Country.toUpperCase().indexOf("MALAYSIA")!=-1)
       {    
            if(productDesc.toUpperCase().indexOf("SV")!=-1)
            {                  
                $(".clstxtlAxis").unbind("change"); 
                $(".clstxtlAxis").change(function()
                {             
                     if(productDesc.toUpperCase().indexOf("SV")!=-1)
                     {
                        alert("2");                                                   
                     }
                }); 
             }
        }
```